Is the subset relationship an actual set according to ZFC?
I'm currently reading and watching about ZFC and Set Theory. In this topic I have a question regarding the subset relationship:
Usually, $x$ is a subset of $y$ iff every member of $x$ is also a member of $y$.
Now, if I try to define this as a relation:
$$\subseteq\:\::= \{(x,y)\mid\forall z: z\in x\Rightarrow z\in y \}$$
To me, this seems to be a relation according to the definition "A set of ordered pairs".
On the other side following set should be a subset of above "$\subseteq$" relation:
$$\{(\{\},y)\mid y=y \}$$
But this "set" is kind of similar to the proper class of all sets.
Therefore, my above definition of the "$\subseteq$" relation seems to be a proper class as well, even bigger than the proper class of all sets.
But how to define the subset relation in this case?
P.S.: I'm new to this community and I wasn't really able to understand how I could incorporate Latex code inside my question.

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

Indeed, your work has shown that, at least in ZFC, ⊆ cannot be encoded as a set, otherwise you can obtain Russell's paradox. Therefore you have no choice but to either reject ZFC or accept that the natural concept of set containment cannot be encoded as a set. Similarly, the powerset concept cannot be encoded as a set.

You cannot define $\subset$ as a binary relation in ZFC. Your definition
$$
\subseteq:=\left\{(x,y):\forall z,z\in x\Longrightarrow z\in y\right\}
$$
Does not work because in ZFC we cannot define a set without specifying a range for its elements. To be more specific, we are only allowed to use axiom schema of specification
$$
\forall X \exists Y=\{u\in X:P(u)\}
$$
But not allowed to use axiom schema of universal specification
$$
\exists Y=\left\{u:P(u)\right\}
$$
Actually axiom schema of universal specification (not included in ZFC) would imply Russel's paradox. However, if we limit the "sets" in context to sets in some universe $\mathcal U$, it is possible to define $\subseteq$ as a set
$$
\subseteq:=\left\{(x,y)\in \mathcal U\times\mathcal U:\forall z\in\mathcal U,z\in x\Longrightarrow z\in y\right\}
$$
Here $z\in x\in\mathcal U$ implies $z\in\mathcal U$ because $\mathcal U$ is a transitive set.

Or indeed $\subseteq:=\left{(x,y)\in \mathcal U\times\mathcal U:\forall z\in x,z\in y\right}$
